# Java NIO taking more time after accepting connection and before doing read

Tags: java, nio

We have a daemon server which listens on a socket. 
We are seeing intermittent behaviour/issue in the server where after accepting client connection, server is taking time before performing read operation.

So after accepting connection, that connection is registers to the selector and then select (3000) method is called and channel interest is changed to read_ops.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to change the `interestOps` to OP_READ *before* calling 'select()`.

Comment: @EJP : Sorry for confusion, OP_READ is happening before select().

Comment: Show the code. This might only mean that the peer isn't sending immediately.